# Creating a separate excel using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a excel with one column that has got information regarding tender. Each cell will have a value like

Column: Nokia([Mode1.Number],OLD)

Column: Motorola([Mode1.Number],OLD)

Column: Motorola([Mode2.Number],NEW)

Column: Motorola([Mode3.Number],OLD)

Column: Samsung([Mode2.Number],NEW)

I need to create 2 excel out of this. One should 've all the information of the OLD and the second excel should've all the information of NEW.

So my output excel should contain

## First Excel

Nokia([Model1.Number])

Motorola([Mode1.Number])

Motorola([Mode3.Number])

## Second Excel

Motorola([Mode2.Number])

Samsung([Mode2.Number])

Kindly help me.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: can anyone reply for this please!!!!

Comment: Do you need two different work books or work sheets? If it is work books how do you plan to manage name conflicts between different versions of the books? What is the frequency that you plan to use this macro? Can the new book delete the old book?

Comment: hi .. sorry for the late reply. Yeah i need two separate excel sheets that contains data that has OLD in it and another one that has NEW in it. I am completely new to this one. Can you please help me .. Thanks in advance. Please

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the cells containing the data you want to copy and then run this code

```
sub copystuff
dim r as range
dim tn as range
im to as range
dim wsNewTarget as worksheet
dim wsOldTarget as worksheet
dim wsSource as worksheet
set wsSource = activesheet
set wsNewtarget = activeworkbook.worksheets.add
set wsoldtarget = activeworkbook.worksheets.add
set tn = wsnewtarget.range("a1")
set to =wsoldtarget.range("a1")
for each r in wssource.selection
    if imstr(r,"NEW")>0 then
          tn=r
           set tn = tn.offset(1,0)
    else
         to=r
           set to = to.offset(1,0)

     end if
next r
end sub
```

Comment: please review line 1 - Sub needs (), and line 14 - imstr() is not a valid VBA function. Also could you explain how in your code subsequent strings get placed below each others instead of overwriting each others. In general I would suggest that code posted here should run at least thru the VBA editor check for syntax errors and obtain proper capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SplitOldNew()
Dim InRange As Range, OldRange As Range, NewRange As Range
Dim Idx As Integer

    Set InRange = Selection                ' select all cells to be split
    Set OldRange = Worksheets("OLD").[A1]  ' choose appropriate target entry points
    Set NewRange = Worksheets("NEW").[A1]  ' ...
    Idx = 1                                ' loop counter

    Do While InRange(Idx, 1) <> ""
        If InStr(1, InRange(Idx, 1), "OLD") <> 0 Then
            DBInsert OldRange, InRange(Idx, 1)
        Else
            DBInsert NewRange, InRange(Idx, 1)
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DBInsert(intoRange As Range, Arg As String)
Dim Idx As Integer

    Idx = 1                                ' loop counter
    Do While intoRange(Idx, 1) <> ""       ' find first blank row
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop

    intoRange(Idx, 1) = Arg                ' write out
End Sub
```